# Update treemodel in real time PySide

Tags: python, pyside, qstandarditemmodel

How can I make it so when I click the Randomize button, for the selected treeview items, the treeview updates to show the changes to data, while maintaining the expanding items states and the users selection? Is this accomplished by subclasses the StandardItemModel or ProxyModel class? Help is much appreciated as I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

It's a very simple example demonstrating the issue. When clicking Randmoize, all it's doing is randomly assigning a new string (name) to each coaches position on the selected Team.

[image]

```
import os
import sys
import random

from PySide2 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
        

class Team(object):

    def __init__(self, name='', nameA='', nameB='', nameC='', nameD=''):
        super(Team, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.headCoach = nameA
        self.assistantCoach = nameB
        self.offensiveCoach = nameC
        self.defensiveCoach = nameD


    def randomize(self):
        names = ['doug', 'adam', 'seth', 'emily', 'kevin', 'mike', 'sarah', 'cassy', 'courtney', 'henry']
        cnt = len(names)-1
        self.headCoach = names[random.randint(0, cnt)]
        self.assistantCoach = names[random.randint(0, cnt)]
        self.offensiveCoach = names[random.randint(0, cnt)]
        self.defensiveCoach = names[random.randint(0, cnt)]
        print('TRADED PLAYERS')


TEAMS = [
    Team('Cowboys', 'doug', 'adam', 'seth', 'emily'),
    Team('Packers'),
    Team('Lakers', 'kevin', 'mike', 'sarah', 'cassy'),
    Team('Yankees', 'courtney', 'henry'),
    Team('Gators'),
]

class MainDialog(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(600,400)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Randomize')

        self.itemModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

        self.proxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.itemModel)
        self.proxyModel.setSortCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.proxyModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.proxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
        self.proxyModel.setFilterKeyColumn(0)

        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.treeView.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        self.treeView.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.treeView.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.treeView.setVerticalScrollMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)
        self.treeView.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.treeView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.treeView.setUniformRowHeights(False)
        self.treeView.header().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.treeView.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)

        self.selectionModel = self.treeView.selectionModel()

        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.treeView)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.mainWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)

        # connections
        self.selectionModel.selectionChanged.connect(self.updateControls)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.randomizeTeams)

        # begin
        self.populateModel()
        self.updateControls()


    def randomizeTeams(self):
        for proxyIndex in self.selectionModel.selectedRows():
            sourceIndex = self.proxyModel.mapToSource(proxyIndex)
            item = self.itemModel.itemFromIndex(sourceIndex)
            team = item.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
            team.randomize()

            # UPDATE UI...


    def updateControls(self):
        self.button.setEnabled(self.selectionModel.hasSelection())


    def populateModel(self):
        self.itemModel.clear()
        self.itemModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Position', 'Name'])

        # add teams
        for ts in TEAMS:
            col1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(ts.name)
            col1.setData(ts, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)

            # add coaches
            childCol1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('Head Coach')
            childCol1.setData(ts, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
            childCol2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(ts.headCoach)
            col1.appendRow([childCol1, childCol2])
            
            childCol1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('Head Coach')
            childCol1.setData(ts, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
            childCol2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(ts.assistantCoach)
            col1.appendRow([childCol1, childCol2])

            childCol1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('Offensive Coach')
            childCol1.setData(ts, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
            childCol2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(ts.offensiveCoach)
            col1.appendRow([childCol1, childCol2])
            
            childCol1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('Defensive Coach')
            childCol1.setData(ts, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
            childCol2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(ts.defensiveCoach)
            col1.appendRow([childCol1, childCol2])

            self.itemModel.appendRow([col1])

        self.itemModel.setSortRole(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        self.itemModel.sort(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.proxyModel.sort(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainDialog()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
    main()
```

Comment: Instead of using QStandardItemModel with values statically set, I'd suggest a custom model, so that the data is directly read by the `Team` object (or its child "nodes"), and randomizing would automatically update the whole structure without losing references and keeping selections.

Comment: do you have any examples demonstrating how to do that. That's something I'm not quite sure i understand how to do in this case

Comment: Any help or example of how i would do this would be much appreciated

Comment: Your `Team` class should be a subclass of `QStandardItem`, which will be the top-level parent in the model. This class should create its own child items (as you are currently doing in the for-loop of `populateModel`), and its `randomize` method should directly reset the item-data of those children. This will ensure the changes are immediately reflected in the model. So - it's really just a matter of taking the code you already have and refactoring it slightly.

Comment: Is this something you could could help me with @ekhumoro in making my sample code work the way you describe?

Comment: @JokerMartini I have posted a basic solution that should work with the example in your question.

Comment: @musicamante Would you demonstrate how to do it with the a custom QStandardItemModel? I'm afraid the solution already provided does not work. I'm not sure i understand how to make custom model for a treeview. ive only seen it done for lists

Comment: @JokerMartini ekhumoro is right, for simple situations, using the QStandardItemModel as basis is actually easier. What is it that doesn't work for you in their answer?

Comment: in my project to change the class object to be a subclass of qstandard item is not ideal. that is why its better to do the subclass of QStandardItemModel instead. im just not sure how to do that for treeviews

Answer (score 0):

Your `Team` class should be a subclass of `QStandardItem`, which will be the top-level parent in the model. This class should create its own child items (as you are currently doing in the for-loop of `populateModel`), and its `randomize` method should directly reset the item-data of those children. This will ensure the changes are immediately reflected in the model.

So - it's really just a matter of taking the code you already have and refactoring it accordingly. For example, something like this should work:

```
TEAMS = {
    'Cowboys': ('doug', 'adam', 'seth', 'emily'),
    'Packers': (),
    'Lakers': ('kevin', 'mike', 'sarah', 'cassy'),
    'Yankees': ('courtney', 'henry'),
    'Gators': (),
    }

class Team(QtGui.QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Team, self).__init__(name)
        for coach in ('Head', 'Assistant', 'Offensive', 'Defensive'):
            childCol1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(f'{coach} Coach')
            childCol2 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            self.appendRow([childCol1, childCol2])

    def populate(self, head='', assistant='', offensive='', defensive=''):
        self.child(0, 1).setText(head)
        self.child(1, 1).setText(assistant)
        self.child(2, 1).setText(offensive)
        self.child(3, 1).setText(defensive)

    def randomize(self, names):
        self.populate(*random.sample(names, 4))

class MainDialog(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    ...
    def randomizeTeams(self):
        for proxyIndex in self.selectionModel.selectedRows():
            sourceIndex = self.proxyModel.mapToSource(proxyIndex)
            item = self.itemModel.itemFromIndex(sourceIndex)
            if not isinstance(item, Team):
                item = item.parent()
            item.randomize(self._coaches)

    def populateModel(self):
        self.itemModel.clear()
        self.itemModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Position', 'Name'])
        self._coaches = []
        # add teams
        for name, coaches in TEAMS.items():
            team = Team(name)
            team.populate(*coaches)
            self._coaches.extend(coaches)
            self.itemModel.appendRow([team])
        self.itemModel.setSortRole(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        self.itemModel.sort(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.proxyModel.sort(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
```